# I need to send data table across server-client connection

Tags: android, sql, database, vb.net, network-programming

I am working on a server-client program, The client connects to the server sending log-in info, so the server checks database, if ok, it reads data from 4 tables and create 1 datatable from them(inner joins)

I need to send the data back to the client, what i am currently doing on the server side is collecting the data and arranging them in a string to send it to the client, and then on the client side, I am extracting the data from the very long string with lots of different delimiters.

Isn't there a better way? Like sending the whole table as an SQL database table, where I can just get what i want in the client side using SQL querys?

I am doing the server in VB.Net and the client is an Android app

Sorry for no codes, I believe the problem is clear enough and it doesn't need any code to explain it.

Comment: Did you try to use JSON to format response data? Android's built-in `JSONObject` and `JSONArray` classes are quite easy to operate and without need of coding/decoding data using your own format. I'm not familiar with .Net but I'm sure you can find some good JSON library for VB.Net

Comment: Json.Net is the library of choice for the .Net side of things:  http://james.newtonking.com/json

Comment: 1 up for JSON. I use it to store complicated arrays of text in SQL field (via VB.net) for basically the same reason as you. Works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Handler in ASP.Net to return the datatable, code is simple as this

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="VB" Class="Handler2" %>

Imports System
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Data

Public Class Handler2 : Implements IHttpHandler

    Public Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest


        ' Dim DTable as Datatable = ..Populate from DB

        Dim Lst As New List(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object))
        For Each Row As DataRow In DTable.Rows
            Dim Dict = New Dictionary(Of String, Object)()
            For Each Col As DataColumn In DTable.Columns
                Dict.Add(Col.ColumnName, Row.Item(Col))
            Next

            Lst.Add(Dict)
        Next 

        Dim js = New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer()  
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json"
        context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(Lst))


    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property IsReusable() As Boolean Implements IHttpHandler.IsReusable
        Get
            Return False
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```